# How to configure NAT to act as port restricted?

Tags: linux, networking, router, nat

I am working on a project which require me to test with different type of NAT. I am using a laptop which is acting as Linux router. Due to some reason it is not able to correctly identify NAT with my stun server.

Here is section of code that I am using

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.203
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i $WAN -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.25.10
iptables -A INPUT -i $WAN   -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $WAN   -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Is there a better way?

[image: setup]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please give more details on your goals and your setup: how are networks 192.168.10./24 and 192.168.25.0/24 related?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae added a image describing setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to configure PAT on your Linux software router?

If yes, please try to following command:

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to
>   172.31.0.23:80
>
> This rule specifies that the NAT table use the built-in PREROUTING
>   chain to forward incoming HTTP requests exclusively to the listed
>   destination IP address of 172.31.0.23.

Here is a good [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html) about how to configure iptables.

Comment: I want my linux router to act as port restricted cone NAT.Added a image describing my setup.